# find average for multiple values in rows and columns in Excel

Tags: excel, match, formula

I need a formula to find average for values if column value in 1:1 matches 15 and row value in A:A matches 750 for example,

here is a screen shot for the table

[image: http://s17.postimg.org/twjqzdj5r/Untitled.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using simoco's setup you could also use an "array formula" with `AVERAGE` function, i.e.

`=AVERAGE(IF((A3:A17=750)*(C1:M1=15),C3:M17))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: a little improvment requires: `=AVERAGE(IF((A3:A17=750)*(C1:M1=15)*(C3:M17<>""),C3:M17))`

Comment: @simoco, Yes, thanks that makes sense, otherwise blanks in qualifying columns are treated as zeroes which can skew the average.......

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C3:M17*(A3:A17=750)*(C1:M1=15))/SUMPRODUCT((C3:M17<>"")*(A3:A17=750)*(C1:M1=15))
```

where

- `A3:A17` address of values in your column A:A
- `C1:M1` address of values in row №1
- `C3:M17` entire target range

First part `SUMPRODUCT(C3:M17*(A3:A17=750)*(C1:M1=15))` gives you *sum* of all values from range `C3:M17` where corresponding value in column A equals to 750 and corresponding value in row №1 equals to 15.

Second part `SUMPRODUCT((C3:M17<>"")*(A3:A17=750)*(C1:M1=15))` gives you *count* of all non empty cells in target range `C3:M17` where corresponding value in column A equals to 750 and corresponding value in row №1 equals to 15.